# Django - Valores iniciales en un modelform maestro-detalle utilizando inlineformset_factory

Tags: django, django-forms

Tengo las siguientes tablas:

models.py

```
class RegistroPago(models.Model):
fechaPago = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
contrato = models.ForeignKey(Contrato, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
formapago = models.ForeignKey(FormaPago, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
nota = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
archivo = models.FileField(upload_to='images/', blank=True)
user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.pk)

class RegistroPagoDato(models.Model):
    registropago = models.ForeignKey(RegistroPago, related_name='items', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # aqui el secreto fue este related_name = 'items'
    categoria = models.ForeignKey(Categoria, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    concepto = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name="Concepto")
    importe = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2, default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        # return self.cliente
        return str(self.pk)
```

en views.py:

```
class CrearRegistroPago(CreateView):
model = RegistroPago
template_name = 'registropago.html'
form_class = RegistroPagoForm
success_url = reverse_lazy('listado_pagos')

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.object = None
    form_class = self.get_form_class()
    form = self.get_form(form_class)
    detalle_orden_registro_pago_formset = DetalleRegistroPagoFormSet()
    return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form, detalle_registro_pago_form_set=detalle_orden_registro_pago_formset))

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    form_class = self.get_form_class()
    form = self.get_form(form_class)
    detalle_registro_pago_form_set = DetalleRegistroPagoFormSet(
        request.POST)

    if form.is_valid() and detalle_registro_pago_form_set.is_valid():
        return self.form_valid(form, detalle_registro_pago_form_set)
    else:
        return self.form_invalid(form, detalle_registro_pago_form_set)

def form_valid(self, form, detalle_registro_pago_form_set):
    form.instance.user = self.request.user
    self.object = form.save()
    detalle_registro_pago_form_set.instance = self.object
    detalle_registro_pago_form_set.save()

    return HttpResponseRedirect(self.success_url)

def form_invalid(self, form, detalle_registro_pago_form_set):
    return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form, detalle_registro_pago_form_set=detalle_registro_pago_form_set))

def get_form_kwargs(self):
    kwargs = super(CrearRegistroPago, self).get_form_kwargs()
    kwargs.update({'user': self.request.user})

    return kwargs
```

en forms.py:

```
class RegistroPagoForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = RegistroPago
    labels = {
        "contrato": "Contrato / Nombre del Inquilino:",
        "fechaPago": "Fecha de Pago:",
        "formapago": "Forma de Pago:",
        "nota": "Agregar Nota:",
    }
    fields = ['fechaPago', 'contrato', 'formapago', 'nota', 'archivo',]

def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
    super(RegistroPagoForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    # self.fields['inquilino'].queryset = Inquilino.objects.all().filter(user=user, status=1)
    self.fields['contrato'].queryset = Contrato.objects.all().filter(user=user, status=1)


    for field in iter(self.fields):
        self.fields[field].widget.attrs.update({
            'class': 'form-control'
        })

class RegistroPagoDatoForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = RegistroPagoDato
    fields = ['categoria', 'concepto', 'importe',]


def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(RegistroPagoDatoForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    for field in iter(self.fields):
        self.fields[field].widget.attrs.update({
            'class': 'form-control'
        })

DetalleRegistroPagoFormSet = inlineformset_factory(RegistroPago, RegistroPagoDato, form=RegistroPagoDatoForm, extra=4)

formset = DetalleRegistroPagoFormSet(initial=[{'categoria': 6, 'concepto': 'probando, 123 probando', 'importe': 999.99}, {'concepto': 'probando, 123 probando'}, {'importe': 999.99},])

for form in formset:
    print(form.as_table())
```

No logro hacer funcionar que cuando quiero capturar un nuevo pago los campos del formulario RegistroPagoDatoForm creado con inlineformset_factory me aparezcan prellenados o con los valores iniciales definidos en:

```
formset = DetalleRegistroPagoFormSet(initial=[{'categoria': 6, 'concepto': 'probando, 123 probando', 'importe': 999.99}, {'concepto': 'probando, 123 probando'}, {'importe': 999.99},])
```

Los curioso es que al ver el html que genera el DetalleRegistroPagoFormSet, ahí si aparecen los valores iniciales:

```
    <tr><th><label for="id_items-0-categoria">Categoria:</label></th><td><select name="items-0-categoria" class="form-control" id="id_items-0-categoria">
  <option value="">---------</option>
  <option value="1">Renta</option>
  <option value="2">Agua</option>
  <option value="3">Electricidad</option>
  <option value="4">Gas</option>
  <option value="5">Intereses</option>
  <option value="6" selected>Depósito</option>
  <option value="7">Mantenimiento</option>
</select></td></tr>
<tr><th><label for="id_items-0-concepto">Concepto:</label></th><td><input type="text" name="items-0-concepto" value="probando, 123 probando" maxlength="150" class="form-control" id="id_items-0-concepto"></td></tr>
<tr><th><label for="id_items-0-importe">Importe:</label></th><td><input type="number" name="items-0-importe" value="999.99" step="0.01" class="form-control" id="id_items-0-importe"></td></tr>
<tr><th><label for="id_items-0-DELETE">Eliminar:</label></th><td><input type="checkbox" name="items-0-DELETE" id="id_items-0-DELETE"><input type="hidden" name="items-0-id" id="id_items-0-id"><input type="hidden" name="items-0-registropago" id="id_items-0-registropago"></td></tr>
<tr><th><label for="id_items-1-categoria">Categoria:</label></th><td><select name="items-1-categoria" class="form-control" id="id_items-1-categoria">
  <option value="" selected>---------</option>
  <option value="1">Renta</option>
  <option value="2">Agua</option>
  <option value="3">Electricidad</option>
  <option value="4">Gas</option>
  <option value="5">Intereses</option>
  <option value="6">Depósito</option>
  <option value="7">Mantenimiento</option>
</select></td></tr>
<tr><th><label for="id_items-1-concepto">Concepto:</label></th><td><input type="text" name="items-1-concepto" value="probando, 123 probando" maxlength="150" class="form-control" id="id_items-1-concepto"></td></tr>
<tr><th><label for="id_items-1-importe">Importe:</label></th><td><input type="number" name="items-1-importe" value="0" step="0.01" class="form-control" id="id_items-1-importe"></td></tr>
<tr><th><label for="id_items-1-DELETE">Eliminar:</label></th><td><input type="checkbox" name="items-1-DELETE" id="id_items-1-DELETE"><input type="hidden" name="items-1-id" id="id_items-1-id"><input type="hidden" name="items-1-registropago" id="id_items-1-registropago"></td></tr>
<tr><th><label for="id_items-2-categoria">Categoria:</label></th><td><select name="items-2-categoria" class="form-control" id="id_items-2-categoria">
  <option value="" selected>---------</option>
  <option value="1">Renta</option>
  <option value="2">Agua</option>
  <option value="3">Electricidad</option>
  <option value="4">Gas</option>
  <option value="5">Intereses</option>
  <option value="6">Depósito</option>
  <option value="7">Mantenimiento</option>
</select></td></tr>
<tr><th><label for="id_items-2-concepto">Concepto:</label></th><td><input type="text" name="items-2-concepto" maxlength="150" class="form-control" id="id_items-2-concepto"></td></tr>
<tr><th><label for="id_items-2-importe">Importe:</label></th><td><input type="number" name="items-2-importe" value="999.99" step="0.01" class="form-control" id="id_items-2-importe"></td></tr>
<tr><th><label for="id_items-2-DELETE">Eliminar:</label></th><td><input type="checkbox" name="items-2-DELETE" id="id_items-2-DELETE"><input type="hidden" name="items-2-id" id="id_items-2-id"><input type="hidden" name="items-2-registropago" id="id_items-2-registropago"></td></tr>
```

pero en el navegador no aparecen:

[image: pantalla sin los valores iniciales que necesito]

Lo que quiero lograr es que al generar un pago, el formulario inicie así:

[image: pantalla como deberia de mostrarse la información]

Muchas gracias por la ayuda!